# What does the term "canonical problem" mean generally?

Tags: mathematical-modeling

What does it mean to say a "canonical problem" in mathematical modelling?

Comment: The usage I am accustomed to is a bit hard to explain, it is a problem that is sort of the "essence" of a bunch of related problems, which is obtained by removing a bunch of details from them. For example the Airy equation provides a canonical problem for the local behavior of $y''+f(t)y=0$ in a vicinity of where $f$ changes sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Canonical" means according to the canon. The canon is a standard form of hymns in orthodox churches. In mathematics it is an aphorism for "as we normally do it", a standard formulation or standard approach.

E.g. we could represent the equivalence classes of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ as $\{[0],[1],[2]\}$ or as $\{[-1],[0],[1]\}$. The first one could be called a canonical representation, as it is the one which is normally used.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to canonical form, then in linear programming that is a problem
written as :

$$\max\{z=c^Tx : Ax \leq b ,\ x \geq 0 \}$$

$$\text{with $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} ,\ c \in \mathbb{R}^{ n} ,\  b \in \mathbb{R}^{m }$ and $x$ a vector of variables in $\mathbb{R}^{n} $}$$